# ggplot: error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot error bars of the two different set of value of y1, y2 with respect to x. In other words, I have two data Y1,Y2 and they are correspond X value. I managed to plot them together after I reshaped the data frame. Now I want to graph the error bars on the same graph for each Y1, Y2 points. I understand `geom_errorbar()` is what I'm looking for. However, I'm following long way to do that and I'm sure there is a short way. What I'm doing I'm calculating "se" for each set and calculate `aes(ymin=y1-se, ymax=y+se)` and repeat the same for Y2. Because I want to apply this error bars to different plots . I 'd rather do it in a short way.

Here my data frame after reshape:

```
M     Req      Rec      load       Un      L1
1    30.11  9.000000   3.000000  30.02000  A
2    50.31  10.030000  6.045000  39.44000  A
3    60.01  11.290000  7.366667  54.93000  A
4    66.10  12.630000  8.827500  68.44500  A
5    80.18  13.106000  9.462000  71.07600  A
6    87.10  14.421667  15.961667 82.70500  A
7    90.08  15.880000  20.644286 94.20714  A
1    4.000  1.500000    1.000000  1        B
2    8.240  6.240000    4.760000  3.00000  B
3    10.28  12.230000  9.420000  4.05000   B
4    18.570 25.570000 17.930000  6.00000   B
5    22.250 35.250000 27.850000  7.00000   B
6    35.070 55.010000 36.810000  8.06000   B
7    48.480  0.420000 47.020000  9.06000   B
```

I have used the following command to graph it:

```
ggplot(df_reshaped,aes(x = M, y = Req, colour = L1, shape=L1)) +  
     geom_point(size = 5)+
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_discrete(name="M") +
     scale_y_continuous(name="Y1 Y2")+
     ggtitle("A vs B")
```

In this case I'm graphing Y1=Req1, Y2=Req2, with respect to x=M

Any short way or suggestion to calculate the error bars ?

Is there any quick way to calculate the "se" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two possibilities to prepare your data for `ggplot`:

- You could aggregate the raw data and plot the results. If you follow this way, you have to calculate the standard errors too since the information cannot be retrieved from the aggregated data. These standard errors could be plotted with `geom_errorbar`.
- A second option is to use the raw data and let `ggplot` do all the calculations for you. This could be done with `stat_summary`. For example:

  ```
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", mult = 1, geom = "errorbar")
  ```

Obviously, you have chosen the first approach. So, you just need to calculate the standard errors for the points of both variables.

Comment: Yes, I have chosen the the first approach. BUT, how to do it in the second approach as I think it's more flexible regardless what data you have. Can you tell me the steps to do it ???

Comment: How would that be applied to my above data. It's not clear to me !!! how would I include it with ggplot ? Thanks

Comment: @Eng.Mohd Please provide example data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I 'd like to apply it to the above sample data.

Comment: @Eng.Mohd As I already mentioned in my answer: You cannot apply it to the above dataset. There is only one value of `Req` for each unique combination of `M` and `L1`. It's not possible to calculate standard errors for one value.